# Firebase Database Programmatically Check downloaded Data Size

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Database for my projects

I would like to build an interface to monitor the data size of each action, when everytime i read it from DB.

I have went through the Firebase documentation and stackoverflow, but doesn't seems like there is any related solution.

Is there anyway to calculate the data size? Achieve it via firebase SDK or client-side JS also acceptable for me. It doesn't have to be 100% match with how firebase calculate the bandwidth or size, but like 80% match is also acceptable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the storage size of downloaded data is quite easy: just `JSON.stringify` the downloaded data. So something like this:

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()).length);
});
```

This misses the side of the outer frame itself, so you'll want to add `snap.key().length` and `'"":{}'.length` for everything else.

For the bandwidth the situation is unfortunately not as easy. Actually half of it is just as easy, since the HTTP bandwidth is pretty close to the JSON storage size that I showed above. You can also easily check this in the Network tab of your browser, where you can see the exact Web Socket frames that are sent and received.

But the tricky bit comes from the fact that all traffic goes over HTTP**S**, and negotiating the SSL connection is dependent on the connection and not on the number of bytes. Modern browsers are quite good at keeping an SSL connection open and reusing it, but it's still a factor that is hard to predict and depends very little on your (or Firebase's) code.

Comment: If put SSL aside, i found a post at the stackexchange to calculate json size in bytes. Should it be correct if i sum up the string size of snap.key and snap.val() ? This is the post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37512/count-byte-length-of-string

Comment: If you just care about payload size, use what I have in my answer to get the size in characters. To convert that to bytes, the link might indeed work (but I didn't try).